# Can I create a form and share it with my private group on Sharepoint O365?

Tags: 2013

I would like the form to be shared on our private group page. I would like once the form is filled out to be kept on a list on that page.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use **Target Audiences** functionality of SharePoint.

   for more details use this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)
2. Another way is you can provide **unique permission** to that list and
   give access to only your private group.

   for more details use this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

Comment: Anil is right. Yes you can, but depending on your environment setup/structure you may choose one path or the other.